# sqlite3_prepare_v2 returns 1 at a specific place

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm working on a c++ database related project. My database has several tables and I have an insert function for each of them in my project. I also have an executeQuery function.

**What needs to happen is the generation of data for the tables. Here is the order:**

1. Basket table
2. Computer table (according to Basket table data)
3. Subsystem table
4. SubsystemTable table (according to both Basket and Computer table data)
5. Subscriber table (according to SubsystemTable table data)
6. Other tables...

**How this is supposed to work:**

1. Reading data from higher-level tables (if necessary). I'm using my own select functions for this purpose. They work fine.
2. According to read data from step one (if it is needed), the insert data is prepared.
3. Preparing query strings from insert data in the *generate*table_name** functions, writing them to a struct which is then passed to *insert*table_name** function.
4. *insert*table_name** function calls *executeQuery* function for each query string from the argument struct.

**The problem:**

Cannot generate Subscriber table after successful generation of the other tables.

*generateSubscriber* function:

```
void ConfigStorage::generateSubscriber(CSubscriberResult* res)
{
#if DEF_PROC_TIME_CHECK
    time_t start, end;
    start = clock();
#endif
    CSubscriberResult ret;
    SUBSYSTEM_TABLE_COLS* subsystemstable;
    int subsystemtable_rows;
    selectSubsystemTable(&ret, subsystemtable_rows, subsystemstable); //checked the select results: they are ok
    if (ret.res.r != 0)
    {
        if (res)
        {
            res->res.s.err = DB_GEN_ERROR;
            res->res.s.code = ret.res.s.err;
        }
        delete [] subsystemstable;
        return;
    }
    SUBSCRIBER* subscriber_insert_data;
    int subscriber_insert_count = 0;
    int subscriber_types_count = sizeof(subscriber_gen_data) / sizeof(subscriber_gen_data[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < subsystemtable_rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < subscriber_types_count; j++)
        {
            if (subsystemstable[i].subsystem == subscriber_gen_data[j].subsystem)
            {
                if (subscriber_gen_data[j].subscribers_per_subsystem == -1)
                {
                    subscriber_insert_count += SUBSCRIBERS_PER_DC;
                }
                else
                {
                    subscriber_insert_count += subscriber_gen_data[j].subscribers_per_subsystem;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    subscriber_insert_data = new SUBSCRIBER[subscriber_insert_count];
    int current = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < subsystemtable_rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < subscriber_types_count; j++)
        {
            if (subsystemstable[i].subsystem == subscriber_gen_data[j].subsystem)
            {
                int subscriber_count;
                if (subscriber_gen_data[j].subscribers_per_subsystem == -1)
                {
                    subscriber_count = SUBSCRIBERS_PER_DC;
                }
                else
                {
                    subscriber_count = subscriber_gen_data[j].subscribers_per_subsystem;
                }
                int subscriber_num = 1;
                for (int k = 0; k < subscriber_count; k++)
                {
                    subscriber_insert_data[current].subsystem = subsystemstable[i].id_subsystemtable;
                    subscriber_insert_data[current].nubmer = randNumber();
                    subscriber_insert_data[current].name = subsystemstable[i].name + " | Subscriber " + itos(subscriber_num++);
                    current++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    insertSubscriber(&ret, current, subscriber_insert_data);
    delete [] subscriber_insert_data;
    delete [] subsystemstable;
    if (ret.res.r != 0)
    {
        if (res)
        {
            res->res.s.err = DB_GEN_ERROR;
            res->res.s.code = ret.res.s.err;
        }
        return;
    }
#if DEF_PROC_TIME_CHECK
    end = clock();
    if (res) res->SetExecTime((end - start) * 1000000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
#endif
}
```

After calling this, the *subscriber_insert_data* struct is prepared and passed to *insertSubscriber*.

*insertSubscriber* function:

```
void ConfigStorage::insertSubscriber(CSubscriberResult* res, int count, SUBSCRIBER* pData)
{
#if DEF_PROC_TIME_CHECK
    time_t start, end;
    start = clock();
#endif
    int r;
    if ((r = executeQuery("begin transaction", NULL, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (res)
        {
            res->res.s.err = BEGIN_TRANSACTION_ERROR;
            res->res.s.code = r;
        }
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        string queryStr = string("insert into subscriber(subsystem, number, name) values(") +
                itos(pData[i].subsystem) + string(", \'") + pData[i].nubmer + string("\', \'") + pData[i].name + string("\')");
        if ((r = executeQuery(queryStr.c_str(), NULL, NULL)) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (res)
            {
                res->res.s.err = OK;
                res->res.s.code = r;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (res)
            {
                res->res.s.err = QUERY_EXECUTION_ERROR;
                res->res.s.code = r;
            }
            executeQuery("rollback", NULL, NULL);
            return;
        }
    }
    if ((r = executeQuery("end transaction", NULL, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (res)
        {
            res->res.s.err = END_TRANSACTION_ERROR;
            res->res.s.code = r;
        }
        return;
    }
#if DEF_PROC_TIME_CHECK
    end = clock();
    if (res) res->SetExecTime((end - start) * 1000000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
#endif
}
```

Here for each *subscriber_insert_data* a *queryStr* is prepared and passed to *executeQuery* function.

*executeQuery* function:

```
int ConfigStorage::executeQuery(const char* queryStr, int *rows, DATA_STRUCT* data)
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    int exec_result;
    exec_result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, queryStr, -1, &statement, 0); //this is where the error originally occurs
    if (exec_result == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        int cols = sqlite3_column_count(statement);
        int result = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            result = sqlite3_step(statement);
            if(result == SQLITE_ROW && rows && data)
            {
                for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
                {
                     data[*rows].data[col] = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, col);
                }
                (*rows)++;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    return exec_result;
}
```

*executeQuery* returns 1 (which is the result of *sqlite3_prepare_v2*) the first time a Subscriber table query is being attempted to execute.

I tried manually executing the query using Sqliteman and it worked fine.

P.S. Each time the program is launched, the database file is overwritten and opened with *sqlite3_open*.

Comment: Why aren't you calling [sqlite3_errmsg()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html)?

Comment: That helped. The error wasn't still quite obvious though.